# State is not changed on click of div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have several DIVs with data attributes. I want to change the attribute `data-sort` of clicked DIV. but it is not working. Every time, I am getting only DESC as the value of `data-sort`.

```js
jQuery(".Cell").click(function() {
  var sort_param = jQuery(this).data("sort");
  jQuery(".Cell").attr("data-sort", "DESC");

  if ("ASC" == sort_param) {
    jQuery(this).attr("data-sort", "DESC");
  } else {
    jQuery(this).attr("data-sort", "ASC");
  }

  alert(jQuery(this).data("key") + "-" + jQuery(this).data("sort"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Cell" data-key="attr1" data-sort="DESC">
  <p>Attr1</p>
</div>
<div class="Cell" data-key="attr2" data-sort="DESC">
  <p>Attr2</p>
</div>
<div class="Cell" data-key="attr3" data-sort="DESC">
  <p>Attr3</p>
</div>
<div class="Cell" data-key="attr4" data-sort="DESC">
  <p>Attr4</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set data attribute like below. I also change your condition to toggle your text.

```js
jQuery(".Cell").attr("data-sort", "DESC");

jQuery(".Cell").on("click", function() {
  var sort_param = jQuery(this).data("sort");
  if ("DESC" === sort_param) {
    jQuery(this).data("sort", "ASC");
  } else {
    jQuery(this).data("sort", "DESC");
  }

  alert(jQuery(this).data("key") + "-" + jQuery(this).data("sort"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Cell" data-key="attr1" data-sort="DESC">
  <p>Attr1</p>
</div>
<div class="Cell" data-key="attr2" data-sort="DESC">
  <p>Attr2</p>
</div>
<div class="Cell" data-key="attr3" data-sort="DESC">
  <p>Attr3</p>
</div>
<div class="Cell" data-key="attr4" data-sort="DESC">
  <p>Attr4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 Perfect! Worked for me. The function I was using to change the Data attribute was used incorrectly. This worked for me.